# Bytes de más al descifrar archivo con Rijndael [papá de AES] (por lo que los checksum también cambian)

Tags: c#, consola, visual-studio-2017, encriptación, criptografía

Estoy retomando el tema de cifrado, anteriormente lo había hecho solo con texto a modo de bloc de notas, hasta ahí todo bien, funciona bien (pueden consultarlo aquí: [Proyecto funcional en GitHub](https://github.com/lopezPWilbert/Win-RinjdaelIO)).

Pero ahora intento aplicar los mismos principios, pero directo a cualquier tipo de archivo (ejecutable, word, iso, etc), al menos la base, funciona, cifra, y descifra, pero al momento de descifrar, ***se vienen datos de más,*** **y no encuentro como evitarlo**, intente borrando el archivo original justo antes de escribir el nuevo descifrado, cosa que no funciona porque es problema al descifrar, igual intente otras formas de escribir el archivo, pero es lo mismo, creo que son temas de conversión, ejemplo:

TEXTO: 123

> CIFRADO: 8
>   ˆWÀ
>   lóº«
>
> DESCIFRADO:123
>   ˆWÀ
>   lóº«

Como ven, me regresa el original, y parte de lo cifrado, y al probar en .exe, al parecer aplica lo mismo (lo verifique comprando las checksum, los cuales obvio cambian al cifrar, pero al descifrar ya no es el del original).

Ejemplo de ejecutables (Checksum SHA 256, instalador de chrome):

> **Original:** D388EA41F9DE27BD5FFC56160400019E83F1EAF75A655BE7BB4A09785C0548AE
>
> **Solo copiar y pegar:** D388EA41F9DE27BD5FFC56160400019E83F1EAF75A655BE7BB4A09785C0548AE
>
> **Cifrado:** 37B006114922C04D7265D8A7FE889A0188DA408B4AEF3DBEB1063A68A37506E3
>
> **Descifrado:** 8404A734958E83A9BE3E94E498F9FF2515278A37D091FBB2D299CDFB4FE180BC

Para sobrescribir el archivo, uso

```
File.WriteAllBytes(archivo, memoryStream.ToArray());
```

Además reemplace del original a ese nuevo, quitando todas las conversiones de UTF8 y Base86, a bytes o equivalentes (WriteAllBytes, ReadAllBytes).

Por ultimo, ese datos de más que se vienen, son al momento de descifrar, ya que al ver todo paso a paso, veo como siempre los últimos bytes no se modifican.

Código completo (La mayor parte del código comentado es del que uso en otro programa para trabajar solo con texto, el cual funciona bien):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace RinjdaelIO_v2
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        string archivo = "C:\\Users\\alumn\\Desktop\\x.txt";

        string strKey = "pass";
        string strIv = "miIV";

        int keySize = 32;
        int ivSize = 16;

        byte[] key = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(strKey);
        byte[] iv = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(strIv);

        Array.Resize(ref key, keySize);
        Array.Resize(ref iv, ivSize);
        while (true)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Opcion");
            string opcion = Console.ReadLine();

            if (opcion == "1")
            {
                encryptString(archivo, key, iv);
                Console.WriteLine("Cifrado: OK");
            }
            if (opcion == "2")
            {
                //descifrado
                decryptString(archivo, key, iv);
                Console.WriteLine("descifrado: OK");
            }


        }


    }
    public static void  encryptString(String archivo, byte[] Key, byte[] IV)
    {
        // Crear una instancia del algoritmo de Rijndael

        Rijndael RijndaelAlg = Rijndael.Create();

        // Establecer un flujo en memoria para el cifrado

        MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();

        // Crear un flujo de cifrado basado en el flujo de los datos

        CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memoryStream,
                                                     RijndaelAlg.CreateEncryptor(Key, IV),
                                                     CryptoStreamMode.Write);

        // Obtener la representación en bytes de la información a cifrar

        //byte[] plainMessageBytes = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(archivo);
        byte[] plainMessageBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(archivo);

        // Cifrar los datos enviándolos al flujo de cifrado

        cryptoStream.Write(plainMessageBytes, 0, plainMessageBytes.Length);

        cryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock();

        // Obtener los datos datos cifrados como un arreglo de bytes

        //byte[] cipherMessageBytes = memoryStream.ToArray();

        //Guardar todo en el archivo
        File.WriteAllBytes(archivo, memoryStream.ToArray());
        // Cerrar los flujos utilizados
        /*
        memoryStream.Close();
        cryptoStream.Close();

        memoryStream.Dispose();
        cryptoStream.Dispose();*/
        // Retornar la representación de texto de los datos cifrados

        //return Convert.ToBase64String(cipherMessageBytes);
    }
    public static void decryptString(String archivo, byte[] Key, byte[] IV)
    {
        // Obtener la representación en bytes del texto cifrado

        // byte[] cipherTextBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(archivo);
        byte[] cipherTextBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(archivo);

        // Crear un arreglo de bytes para almacenar los datos descifrados

        byte[] plainTextBytes = new byte[cipherTextBytes.Length];

        // Crear una instancia del algoritmo de Rijndael

        Rijndael RijndaelAlg = Rijndael.Create();

        // Crear un flujo en memoria con la representación de bytes de la información cifrada

        MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream(cipherTextBytes);

        // Crear un flujo de descifrado basado en el flujo de los datos

        CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memoryStream,
                                                     RijndaelAlg.CreateDecryptor(Key, IV),
                                                     CryptoStreamMode.Read);

        // Obtener los datos descifrados obteniéndolos del flujo de descifrado
        int a=cryptoStream.Read(cipherTextBytes, 0, cipherTextBytes.Length);

        //Esta linea da error, acabo de corregir
        //cryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock();

        //int decryptedByteCount = cryptoStream.Read(plainTextBytes, 0, plainTextBytes.Length);

           // File.Delete(archivo);

        File.WriteAllBytes(archivo, memoryStream.ToArray());

        // Cerrar los flujos utilizados
        /*
        memoryStream.Close();
        cryptoStream.Close();
        memoryStream.Dispose();
        cryptoStream.Dispose();*/
        // Retornar la representación de texto de los datos descifrados

        //return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(plainTextBytes, 0, decryptedByteCount);
    }
}}
```

Comment: No entiendo como cambiaste cryptoStream.Read por cryptoStream.Write.. Uno lee.. el otro graba.. hacen dos cosas totalmente distintas...

Comment: Bueno, lo menciono ahí debajo, me arroja una excepción si lo mantengo como era originalmente.

Comment: pero alex, no estas cambiando una funcion por una similar. Estas cambiando una de salida por una de entrada!

Comment: Listo, al parecer copie mal el código del original, cambie CryptoStreamMode.Write por CryptoStreamMode.Read. Aún así el problema persiste.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Después de buscar código o proyectos que hicieran lo mismo de cifrar archivos, di con esta consulta, y utilice unas lineas donde guarda en el archivo lo descifrado: [Encriptar y desencriptar archivos](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/expression/es-ES/73a6446f-23c6-408c-9a8b-612f0ef7aff5/encriptar-y-desencriptar-archivos-?forum=vcses)

Al final, solo se cambia la forma en que se escribirán los archivos al descifrar, así que el método decryptString(), quedará así:

```
public static void decryptString(String archivo, byte[] Key, byte[] IV)
    {
        // Obtener la representación en bytes del texto cifrado

        // byte[] cipherTextBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(archivo);
        byte[] cipherTextBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(archivo);

        // Crear un arreglo de bytes para almacenar los datos descifrados

        byte[] plainTextBytes = new byte[cipherTextBytes.Length];

        // Crear una instancia del algoritmo de Rijndael

        Rijndael RijndaelAlg = Rijndael.Create();

        // Crear un flujo en memoria con la representación de bytes de la información cifrada

        MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream(cipherTextBytes);

        // Crear un flujo de descifrado basado en el flujo de los datos

        CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memoryStream,
                                                     RijndaelAlg.CreateDecryptor(Key, IV),
                                                     CryptoStreamMode.Read);

        // Obtener los datos descifrados obteniéndolos del flujo de descifrado

        //Funciona pero mete datos de mas
        //int a=cryptoStream.Read(cipherTextBytes, 0, cipherTextBytes.Length);
        FileStream fsOut = new FileStream(archivo, FileMode.Create);

        int data;
        while ((data = cryptoStream.ReadByte()) != -1)
        {
            fsOut.WriteByte((byte)data);
        }
        fsOut.Close();

        //Funciona pero mete datos de mas
        //File.WriteAllBytes(archivo, memoryStream.ToArray());

    }
```